# Fetching Data from DB using PDO with Class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Why is it that only the first sets of data are displayed and not the entire data?

Here is my code..(Sorry, still new to OOP)

```
include 'crud.php';

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_name = "crud";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);


$select = new Crud($conn);
$select->crud_select();
```

crud.php

```
class Crud
{
    private $conn;
    public function __construct($conn){
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }
    public function crud_insert($lname, $fname, $address, $age){

    }
    public function crud_select(){
        $result = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM personal_info");
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();
        if($count == 0){
            $no_files = "No file(s) found!";
            echo $no_files;
        }
        else{
            $row = $result->fetch();
            echo $row['last_name'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['address'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['age'] . "<br/>";
        }   
    }
}
```

if i'm trying `fetchAll()` it's not displaying anything.

Comment: Use `fetchAll` along with loop.

Comment: Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have fetch only one row. If you wanted to fetch multiple rows then you need a loop

```
        $result->execute();

        $count = $result->rowCount();
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($count == 0){
            $no_files = "No file(s) found!";
            echo $no_files;
        }

  else{
    while($row = $result->fetch()){
                echo $row['last_name'] . "<br/>";
                echo $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
                echo $row['address'] . "<br/>";
                echo $row['age'] . "<br/>";     
     }
    }
```

or you can fetch array like this:

```
        $result->execute();        
        $count = $result->rowCount();

        if($count == 0){
            $no_files = "No file(s) found!";
            echo $no_files;
        }

  else{

        $resultset = $datas->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach($resultset as $row){
                    echo $row['last_name'] . "<br/>";
                    echo $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
                    echo $row['address'] . "<br/>";
                    echo $row['age'] . "<br/>";     
         }
        }
```

Comment: the first code is working.. i don't know what's wrong with the second. and btw, i remove `;` in the `$row = $result->fetch();`

Comment: Need to set fetch mode. it should work now @user3569641

Answer (score 2):

you should place the fetch in while loop to get all the results printed

```
while($row = $result->fetch())
{
            echo $row['last_name'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['address'] . "<br/>";
            echo $row['age'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: it's not working.. Undefined index for last_name, first_name, address and age.

Comment: do you have the values in db for them ?

Comment: check var_dump($row) with in the loop to see all fetched

Comment: did you try var_dump with in the loop ?